# Jupyter notebook is not opening

Tags: ubuntu

I am using this command to install jupyter: `sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root`
But is showing

> xdg-open: no method available for opening 'file:///home/souvik/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-19267-open.html'

Could you please suggest me how to sort this out?

Comment: The error message suggests that jupyter tries to open a web browser but does not know which one (xdg has methods of linking file types to applications to open the file with). Try opening an HTML file (perhaps the one listed) by double-clicking in a file manager and tell us what happens.

Comment: ... In fact, what happens when you try `xdg-open file:///home/souvik/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-19267-open.html` - or, if you do not have it, a different html file?

Comment: If I open the link using xdg-open then also it is not opening.  It says file not found.

Comment: I thought this might be a temporary file, that's why I wrote " - or, if you do not have it, a different html file".  You do not have that temporary file.  So: What happens when you enter `xdg-open http://www.startpage.com/` - does it load a browser?